# Select date between two dates

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this select statement to return number of rows between two dates. It only returns one while while there are foure rows.

```
SELECT count(*) as number 
  FROM PFServicesLogging 
 WHERE User_ID = '784198013531599' 
   AND ServiceType = 1 
   AND InsertDate between "2013-11-11" and "2013-11-19"
```

table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE `PFServicesLogging`

(
       ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
       ServiceType INTEGER NOT NULL,
       Datetime DATETIME,
       User_ID TEXT,
       Frequency INTEGER, `InsertDate`  Date,
       PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)
```

Comment: Please include the table structure and some sample data. Especially show us some values of `InsertDate`.

Comment: Are all dates in database formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD` (4-2-2)?

Comment: You may need to add the time `23:59:59` on the to date if its a DateTime field

Comment: @Fred, well noticed! However better use `<2013-11-20` as time format may be `HH:MM:SS.SSS...`

Comment: i used greater than and lower than the same issue and the feild is date only in YYYY-MM-DD format

Comment: If you take `AND InsertDate between "2013-11-11" and "2013-11-19"` off the where clause do you see the 4 rows? Can you post exactly what these dates are? Also are we right to assume `InsertDate` is a DateTime datatype?

Comment: dates is 2013-11-13 and 2013-11-14 InsertDate is date type not datetime

Comment: For SQLite `DATE` or `DATETIME` stands for `NUMERIC` (check [affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity)). Better use nothing or `TEXT` in your case!

Comment: @BadrHussien Post your data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your date fields include the time of day, do not use between.  Use

```
where YourDateField >= StartDate
and YourDateField < TheDayAfterTheEndDate
```

**Edit Starts Here**

Reading the comments, maybe the problem has nothing to do with the dates.  Maybe it's the user_id or service type.  To troubleshoot, replace your where clause with

```
where 1 = 1
/*
User_ID = '784198013531599' 
AND ServiceType = 1 
AND InsertDate between "2013-11-11" and "2013-11-19"
*/
```

and run your query.  Take your filters out of the comment block one by one so that you can see which one causes the unexpected results.

Comment: +1 Alternatively, `DATE(YourDateField) BETWEEN StartDate
AND EndDate` would work, but your solution implies less computation!

Comment: i used greater than and lower than the same issue and the feild is date only in YYYY-MM-DD format – Badr Hussien just now edit